# How might I quickly determine the equation of the parabola, given the coordinates of its focus and vertex?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

I have this MCQ.

> Which of the following is the equation of the parabola with focus at 
>   $(1,2)$ and vertex at 
>   $(3,2)$ :
>
> A.  $ y^2 - 4y + 8x - 20 = 0 $
>
> B.  $ y^2 + y + 8x -20 = 0 $
>
> C.  $ y^2 + 4y + 8x - 20 = 0 $
>
> D.  $ y^2 - 4y + x - 20 = 0 $
>
> E.  $ y^2 - 4y + 8x + 20 = 0 $

Now, I know how to find equation of a parabola from focus and vertex, or from directrix and vertex, but that takes some time. I was wondering if there is a way to just sort of *see* which equation is the right one, because right from the focus and vertex we can see that the parabola will open on the left and its equation will be $y^2 = - 4ax$.

I'm not sure if it's actually possible though, but I think it would be cool if there was a way.

Comment: If you know how to do the work then do the work.

Comment: For a parabola like $y=ax^2+bx+c$ the vertex is located at the point where the derivative vanishes. This is, when $2ax+b=0$, or what is the same $x=-\frac{b}{2a}$. In your case $x$ and $y$ are exchanged. You can see that only A,D, and E result in a vertex where $y=2$. Of those only A results in $x=3$ when $y=2$. Then you only need to check if A has focus at $(1,2)$.

Comment: Why are people voting this question down? This genuinely perplexes me!

Comment: By the way, the equation wouldn't be $y^2 = -4ax$, it would be $(y-\color{red}{k})^2 = -4a(x-\color{red}{h})$, where $(h,k)$ is the vertex (which is known here). Also, $a$ is the focal length, which you can deduce since you are given the focus and vertex. So since you can easily work out $a$ and know $h,k$, you can put them into $(y-\color{red}{k})^2 = -4a(x-\color{red}{h})$, and then expand and rearrange to get the desired answer.

Comment: @JohnDouma Well in most of the MCQ type questions you aren't really supposed to do ALL the work. If it was like a written exam then that would make sense but not in these ones. It's like the choice between fully solving one question or attempting five others instead.

Comment: The vertex tells you that A. is the only possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any particular formula here: just plug the coordinates of the vertex into the equation and you'll see that only in case A the point belongs to the parabola.

Comment: Jesus how did I forget to PITA